# AVPlayer starts, but video pauses for slight delay

Tags: ios, swift3, avplayer

I have read about delays in AVPlayer start up, but not exactly my case, and I havent found a solution.

I have some mp4 videos stored locally in app, and am using AVPlayer to play it. The problem is when the video clip starts, the player opens and you see the video beginning, but it freezes for less than a second before, then it starts to play. This delay disturbs me. Is there anything I can do.

I tried seeking to a later time in the video, but it didn't change anything

Here is some code, can give more if i need.

Thanks

This I do in viewDidLoad

```
    let videoString:String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "cat2", ofType: ".mp4")


    if let url = videoString{

        let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: url)

        self.player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)


        self.playerController.player = self.player



    }
```

Then on the button click I call:

```
 func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {



    let tappedImage = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView



    // Your action

    self.present(self.playerController, animated: true, completion: {

        print("Pic tapped")

        self.playerController.player?.play()



    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put:

```
self.playerController.player?.play()
```

Before:

```
 self.present(self.playerController, animated: true, completion: {
```